# qooxdoo qx.Desktop : set Grid layout to full screen

Tags: qooxdoo

Maybe this is a newbie question, how to set grid layout to full screen ?

My current code is :

```
    var container = new qx.ui.container.Composite().set({
        decorator: "main",
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        allowGrowX: false,
        allowGrowY: false
    });
    var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(2,2);
    layout.setSpacing(5);
    container.setLayout(layout);

    var w1 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();
    var w2 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();
    var w3 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();
    var w4 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();

    container.add(w1, {row: 0, column: 0});
    container.add(w2, {row: 0, column: 1});
    container.add(w3, {row: 1, column: 0});
    container.add(w4, {row: 1, column: 1});
    container.set({backgroundColor : "white"});
    this.getRoot().add(container, {edge: 0});
```

What did I miss ? It occupies only small part of the browser .

p.s. I am working on `qx.Desktop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Grid layout occupy full screen, I have to add :

```
layout.setRowFlex(1, 1);
layout.setColumnFlex(1, 1);
```

after `var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(2,2);` .

The code is to set the width & height of the grid at (1,1) of the Grid Layour flexible. For function `setRowFlex()` or `setColumnFlex()` , the 1st parameter is the index of the grid, while second parameter sets whether the grid has flexible width / height ( 1 = Flexible , 0 = Fixed )

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
...
allowGrowX: true,
allowGrowY: true
...
```

?! (Just think of the names).